# How to bind data to DataGrid by databinding correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have such DataGrid

```
<UserControl x:Class="TV_MeshCreator.UserControls.UCClipProcessing"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TV_MeshCreator.UserControls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TV_MeshCreatorEngine.Model.Binding;assembly=TV_MeshCreatorEngine"
             Background="WhiteSmoke"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="600">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:UCClipProcessingModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

                <GroupBox Header="Main configuration :" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

                      Height="Auto">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  x:Name="Lv_clip_folders"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              MinHeight="150"
                                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Lv_clip_folders_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                  MaxHeight="150"
                              Margin="4, 4, 4, 4"
                              Grid.Column="0"/>-->

                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=GridItems}"
                                x:Name="Dg_main_configuration"
                                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                      AlternatingRowBackground="LightYellow"
                                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                                      MinHeight="150"
                                      MaxHeight="150"
                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path to calibration folder" Binding="{Binding ClipFolder}"/>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Geometry calibration folder"/>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Color calibration folder"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>

.......
......
```

So, as you can see I set context

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:UCClipProcessingModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then in my `UCClipPresessing.xalm.cs` I am creating

```
        public UCClipProcessing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Model = new UCClipProcessingModel();
        }
```

Then I have a method that fill my items

```
        public void UpdateCLipProcessingGridItems(IList<ClipProcessingGridItem> folderList)
        {
            if (folderList != null)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    foreach (ClipProcessingGridItem tmp in folderList)
                    {
                        Model.GridItems.Add(tmp);
                    }

                });
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: folderList or empty or null");
            }
        }
```

and eventually

```
    public class UCClipProcessingModel : BaseModel
    {
        private IList<ClipProcessingGridItem> _GridItems { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ClipProcessingGridItem> GridItems
        {
            get { return GridItems; }
            set { GridItems = value; }
        }
    }
```

and

```
    public class ClipProcessingGridItem
    {
        public MCClipFolder ClipFolder { get; set; }

        //in future a few properties more will be here
    }
```

But when I start my program I don't see nothing...

I am not clearly understand how `.xalm` know which exactly `UCClipProcessingModel` object I am going to bind? Because I think that object that I set in `.xalm` and object that I create in `.cs` file is not the same object..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong.

You have two UCClipProcessingModel instances, one in the DataContext, one in the Model property. Use only one, e.g. by

```
Model = (UCClipProcessingModel)DataContext;
```

The ItemsSource Binding declaration is wrong. Use Path instead of Source:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridItems}" ...>
```

or just

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" ...>
```

The GridItems property declaration is broken. Declare a readonly auto-implemented property like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClipProcessingGridItem> GridItems { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ClipProcessingGridItem>();
```

It's unclear why you use the control's Dispatcher. This should also work:

```
if (folderList != null)
{
    foreach (var item in folderList)
    {
        Model.GridItems.Add(var);
    }
}
```

or perhaps without the Model property, which seems redundant anyway:

```
if (folderList != null)
{
    foreach (var item in folderList)
    {
        ((UCClipProcessingModel)DataContext).GridItems.Add(var);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I would like to ask one more quesiton, how can I scroll down the DataGrid after item was added? Because of now each time when I add new line it is added to the bottom and user should scroll down in order to see this line, I would like to do it programatically

Comment: There is a ScrollIntoView method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.scrollintoview?view=netframework-4.8